# Coroutines - Dispatchers.Main.immediate with join is deadlocking inside runBlocking

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Breaking down a simple case on Android to suspend the main thread and perform concurrent processing with coroutines, the following code only prints `Launched` and `runBlocking` never completes:

```
runBlocking {
      val ioJob = launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        delay(1000)
      }
      val mainJob = launch(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) {
        Log.d("Routine", "Launched")
        ioJob.join()
        Log.d("Routine", "Joined")
      }

      listOf(mainJob, ioJob).joinAll()
    }
```

Of course if we replace `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` with `Dispatchers.IO` everything works great, but some of my concurrent processing should be run on main. Using `Dispatchers.Main` doesn't log anything, as expected.  It appears that once a `join` is performed within the root of `runBlocking` it paralyzes anything suspended that was dispatched to main.

Worth noting, an approach predicated on `CountDownLatch` and threads works great:

```
    val latchMain = CountDownLatch(1)
    val primaryLatch = CountDownLatch(2)

    val ioExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(Executors.defaultThreadFactory())

    log("Execute IO")
    ioExecutor.execute(
        Runnable {
          log("Delay IO")
          Thread.sleep(1000)
          log("Countdown Main")
          latchMain.countDown()
          Thread.sleep(3000)
          primaryLatch.countDown()
        })

    log("Execute Main")
    Runnable {
      log("Await Main")
      latchMain.await()
      log("Countdown Primary")
      primaryLatch.countDown()
    }.run()

    log("Await Primary")
    primaryLatch.await()
    log("Continue")

    stepTracker.endTracking()
    return stepTracker.stepGraphTrace
  }

  private fun log(msg: String) = Log.i("Routine", "[${Thread.currentThread().name}] $msg")
```

With output:

```
2021-08-11 11:04:06.508 [main] Execute IO
2021-08-11 11:04:06.509 [main] Execute Main
2021-08-11 11:04:06.510 [main] Await Main
2021-08-11 11:04:06.510 [pool-25-thread-1] Delay IO
2021-08-11 11:04:07.512 [pool-25-thread-1] Countdown Main
2021-08-11 11:04:07.513 [main] Countdown Primary
2021-08-11 11:04:07.513 [main] Await Primary
2021-08-11 11:04:10.514 [main] Continue
```

Any ideas?  About to go submit an issue to JetBrains on this one.

Comment: Running it from an Android process.  Besides that, the `mainJob` does in fact launch using `immediate`; not pictured is other debugging I did to ensure things were correctly running on main thread.

Comment: If it's expected that `Dispatchers.Main` doesn't log anything, then I don't understand why it's surprising that `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` logs something before deadlocking. You are surprised that `Main.immediate` makes more progress than `Main`?

Comment: Not surprised, disappointed that I can get `ioJob.join()` onto the main thread by using immediate, before `joinAll` is placed onto main in `runBlocking`, but am unable resume suspended execution inside `mainJob` due to how `runBlocking` totally blocks the main thread on `joinAll`.   Java threading gives the ability to do this per the latch based implementation on the original post, and I'd hope a similar capability exists in coroutines, I just haven't been able to find it.

Comment: The thread used by `Dispatchers.Main` already runs an event loop, you don't need `runBlocking` to install an event loop to it. You should just not use `runBlocking` at all. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: I want to suspend the non-coroutine main thread, execution while the coroutines perform my concurrent processing, some of which may need to be run on the main thread - think of a DAG where most processing is run in parallel on IO but perhaps it needs to occasionally update a UI during processing.

Comment: But why call `runBlocking` on the main thread? That will freeze your UI regardless if you could do this. Why not use `scope.launch` instead?

Comment: That plan can't possibly work -- you can't ever block the UI thread. It isn't there just to run your occasional update task, it serves thousands of tasks every second, literally no pixel on screen changes without the UI thread taking an action to change it.

Comment: Oh, but indeed it CAN work - in both Java and per @J.Grbo's solution below for coroutines.  `runBlocking` is a unique beast.

Comment: It can't work. The UI thread is blocked by the mentioned "solution".

Comment: If by "work" you mean "there's no deadlock", then yes. But that's beside the point, you blocked the UI for as long as those jobs were executing.

Comment: That's correct, the UI is totally blocked while runBlocking and all of its children are active, nothing can be rendered on the screen, it's frozen, but that was the desire of the author as far as I understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: To clear things out, one should not deliberately block the main/UI thread with `runBlocking`, because while the UI thread get's released inside `runBlocking` (if it suspends) for its child coroutines, nothing outside the `runBlocking` gets executed (no draw methods, nothing), which leads to frozen UI for as long as runBlocking is active.

It's probably due to how "`immediate`" is implemented. It's not just `join()`, it's
any suspend function, if you call `yield()` it won't help, and if you call `delay()`
`mainJob` will resume only when the delay is done. Basically `mainJob` will not
resume as long as `runBlocking` is running, and `runBlocking` will not finish until
`mainJob` is done, which is a **deadlock** by definition.

You can omit specifying `Dispatcher.Main.immediate` to the `mainJob` and let it
inherit its context from `runBlocking`. And if you want to start executing `mainJob` as soon
as its declared just yield the thread from `runBlocking` to it.

```
runBlocking {
    log("runBlocking: start")

    val ioJob = launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        log("ioJob: About to delay")
        delay(1000)
        log("ioJob: Delay done")
    }

    val mainJob = launch {
        log("mainJob: About to join ioJob")
        ioJob.join()
        log("mainJob: ioJob successfully joined")
    }


    // yield() if you want to start executing mainJob before the rest of the runBlocking code

    log("runBlocking: about to join jobs")
    listOf(ioJob, mainJob).joinAll()
    log("runBlocking: jobs joined, exiting")
}

private fun log(msg: String) = Log.i("MainActivity", "[${Thread.currentThread().name}] $msg")
```

w/o yield()

```
I/MainActivity: [main] runBlocking: start
I/MainActivity: [main] runBlocking: about to join jobs
I/MainActivity: [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] ioJob: About to delay
I/MainActivity: [main] mainJob: About to join ioJob
I/MainActivity: [DefaultDispatcher-worker-3] ioJob: Delay done
I/MainActivity: [main] mainJob: ioJob successfully joined
I/MainActivity: [main] runBlocking: jobs joined, exiting
```

[image]

Comment: You, sir, are an epic hero.  My colleague suggested a similar approach, but I somehow goofed it up.  This is exactly what I was looking for; I need to spend more time understanding parent/child relationships and inherited context.

Comment: Also worth noting, looking at source code for `runBlocking` is pretty scary, it is definitely a unique context unlike any others.

Comment: Its uniqueness lies in the fact that it implements its own event loop, whereas all other dispatchers are just glue code to use an existing event loop: either the GUI or an executor.

Comment: Thanks for that detail.

Comment: Once again, this answer is simply awesome @J.Grbo , and the various explanations around this question from @Marko Topolnik are great too.  Inheriting context from `runBlocking` provides a host of options to run concurrent operations on both IO and Main threads when the most external `runBlocking` is performed on Main.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this `runBlocking` code is called from the main thread, then the inner coroutine launched on Dispatchers.Main will never reach the front of the queue on the main thread looper because `runBlocking` is still blocking the main thread, so the coroutine can never start.

When you use `Main.immediate`, the beginning of the launched coroutine can at least run because `immediate` runs the coroutine *up to the first suspension point* if you're already on the main thread, which you are if you launched `runBlocking` on the main thread. When it reaches the suspend function call `join()`, it gets put in the main thread looper's queue and you're back to the same problem as above. Suspend function calls always break up the continuation of the coroutine.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just adding the blocking happens because Dispatchers.Main is single threaded (doc says: "Usually such dispatcher is single-threaded"). If runBlocking and the mainJob would use a dispatcher with a thread pool, then the code would work.

Comment: Indeed, that's just the trick, I want to run a mix of IO and Main-thread bound concurrent processing, and not just a basic thread pool, while suspending the main thread. It's fine if coroutines don't support this use case, but I'm hoping to migrate some latch based code.

Comment: As per docs, runBlocking runs a coroutine and blocks the thread
in which this coroutine runs until its completion. Which means if this parent coroutine suspends, thread gets released for other child coroutines in the queue to be run. And this exactly happens when one implicitly inherits the runBlocking's coroutineContext (as in my example above). But for whatever reason if one explicitly declares child corutines' CoroutineDispatcher, releasing the blocked thread by suspending the runBlocking doesn't hand the released thread for other suspended child coroutines to use it.

Comment: @Kevin the latch based solution isn't the same as the coroutine based one. Runnable {} .run() is not running anything concurrently (no threading involved). Creating a Runnable and running it manually by calling run() is like running the code in the Runnable directly, the Runnable is just a wrapper and obsolete.

Comment: @J.Grbo thanks for that comment, doesn't explain why it's implemented that way under the hood, but definitely explains what we're seeing.

Comment: `runBlocking` never suspends, that's what `blocking` means in its name. Also, a thread never suspends, at least not in the coroutine sense. The OS decides when to suspend a thread, that is, take it off the CPU and park its execution state for later resumption. That meaning of "suspend" is irrelevant here.

Comment: `if this parent coroutine suspends, thread gets released for other child coroutines in the queue to be run.` This is true, but the thread will never get released to let the top-level GUI event loop serve more events. You are focusing on solving a subproblem while leaving the main problem, freezing the GUI, out of sight.

Comment: @Marko that's correct, other code (draw methods, including other coroutines scheduled on UI thread) won't run until the runBlocking completely finishes with all of its children. I was focusing on answering the actual question of the author, not ton the "problems" using runBlocking will cause.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik in this case, it's during a startup procedure where we need to guarantee initialization before proceeding to UI, and we do want to block things from moving forward.  But this is making me consider some other techniques for my actual use case that will be more flexible.  Really appreciate yours and others' feedback on this.

Comment: With a reactive/observer approach, you can show a blank or loading screen initially, and the UI can proceed when the startup procedure is complete. Then you can avoid making the UI freeze and seem janky during that start-up time. It affects not just your own UI, but everything on the system, like pulling down notifications.

Comment: This initialization problem is tricky, something that would be very simple in the world of a server-side application turns into a problem that needs a bunch of new mechanisms to work right. You just have to live with the fact that you can't get everything initialized before your app has already started running. You need a new application state or phase, typically covered by a splash screen, where you do the init while most of the moving parts of the application aren't yet created.

Comment: @Kevin I've updated the answer with the note at the top, as for your use case, you may do the initialization in the App's onCreate() method, it will not render any UI until it's done. But as Marko said, initialization should be done while splash screen is being presented to a user.

Answer (score 2):

Not answering the original question but questioning the question itself ;-).

The latch based solution "pretends" to use concurrency for both "jobs" but only the io job does. The second Runnable is just wrapping the code to run and does nothing.

This is doing the exact same thing but simpler:

```
val latchMain = CountDownLatch(1)
val ioExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(Executors.defaultThreadFactory())

ioExecutor.execute(
    Runnable {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        latchMain.countDown()
    }
)

latchMain.await()
```

The "identical" coroutine based implementation is very simple:

```
runBlocking {
    val ioJob = launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        delay(1000)
    }

    ioJob.join()
}
```

Or using the same thread pool for the io job:

```
runBlocking {
    val ioJob = launch(ioExecutor.asCoroutineDispatcher()) {
        delay(1000)
    }

    ioJob.join()
}
```

Comment: You're right!  I was not comparing apples to apples here in my base case, under the hood my scenario turns out more complex, where I actually have N-jobs that run as a DAG, and there can be multiple main-thread jobs intermixed.  In the latch solution, I run all the main jobs one after the other in the end, and as each runs, it may provide inputs into other io jobs which in turn can unlock the next main job.  I've updated my original example.

Comment: You didn't make any substantial change in your updated example. This answer still applies exactly the same way. You still have that no-op `Runnable{ someCode() }.run()`, equivalent to just `someCode()`, and you have one extra thread that releases the latch. Very simple scenario, just like Emanuel shows in this answer.

Comment: BTW @Emanuel I think you don't even need `Dispatchers.IO` there, then you have a setup that does with two coroutines on one thread the equivalent of what the first example achieves with two threads.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik without the Dispatchers.IO the ioJob would run in the same CoroutineScope as the runBlocking (main thread) while the latch based ioJob uses its own thread pool.

Comment: Actually you're running it in the same coroutine scope this way too, just switching the dispatcher. It's still a child job in the `runBlocking` scope. The whole point of coroutines is that you don't need the equivalent of a thread pool (a "coroutine pool"). Thread pools are a hack to work around their being expensive to create and destroy.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik `runBlocking` and `launch` have their own scope, one being the child scope of the parent scope. That's true regardless whether you define a dispatcher or not. The difference is that when using `Dispatchers.IO` it will use a CoroutineDispatcher (is a CoroutineContext) "designed for offloading blocking IO tasks to a shared pool of threads". Without `Dispatchers.IO` it's using the parent scope dispatcher = `main` which is dispatching on the UI thread. Coroutines are just syntactic sugar on top of threads ;-), it's still threads and thread pools underneath.

Comment: We usually use "scope" to refer to the whole hierarchy, but you're technically right in your last comment, however it's in contradiction with the earlier comment (which states that without `Dispatchers.IO`, `launch` would use the same scope as `runBlocking`). You also proceed to basically state my point -- you don't have to dispatch to another thread pool to launch that coroutine (it isn't blocking), and that's the point of coroutines -- concurrency on a single thread. Coroutines aren't syntactic sugar on top of threads, they are sugar on top of continuation-based programming.

Comment: Coroutines use continuation and run on top of threads, meaning they are neither sugar on top of continuation-based programming nor sugar on top of threads. From https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html: "The coroutine context includes a coroutine dispatcher that determines what thread or threads the corresponding coroutine uses for its execution". From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine#Comparison_with_threads: "Coroutines are very similar to threads. However, coroutines are cooperatively multitasked, whereas threads are typically preemptively multitasked".

Comment: You are again making self-contradictory comments ("Coroutines are just syntactic sugar on top of threads" vs. "they are neither sugar on top of continuation-based programming nor sugar on top of threads"), but I guess you're learning, which is good. On the JVM, a coroutine compiles into bytecode that uses the continuation-passing style of invocation, but otherwise I agree Kotlin coroutines aren't syntactic sugar in general. Back to the main point: I hope by now you have made the realization that you don't need `Dispatchers.IO` for your coroutine containing just a `delay`.

Comment: Yes one of us is learning and I still disagree that Dispatcher.IO isn't needed. The goal was to mirror the latch based solution as closely as possible and since the io job runs on a separate thread using the IO dispatcher is a better match than using the main dispatcher which will run it on the ui thread (on Android). It's not about blocking vs. non-blocking in this case, it's about threading.

Comment: My suggestion was to use the same dispatcher for both coroutines (the `runBlocking` one). That would establish an analogy where you replace the concept of a thread with that of a coroutine. Instead, your example presents an uneasy mix of threads and coroutines, whose best analog in the thread world would be pinning each thread to a different core (since threads are to coroutines what CPU cores are to threads). The analogy breaks also because, whereas `sleep()` occupies its thread, `delay()` does not occupy any threads.

Comment: I see your point but imo you're overthinking the analogy part. `delay` and `sleep` are placeholders for long-running operations so the nature of those two (blocking vs. suspending) is not really relevant. Of course you can argue that the long running operation would be suspending as well if we go with a coroutine based solution which might or might not be true (so much legacy code out there...). Anyway I enjoyed the discussion and did learn a thing or two even if my main point was to question the question which has several flaws (blocking the ui and comparing apples to oranges).

Comment: I fully acknowledge it's obsession with detail :) but it also cuts into the essence of coroutines. A better way to say what I wanted was that I'd prefer to remove any mention of dispatchers from the example, because it's a lower-level concern. We never have to deal with CPU core assignment in the "thread world", so when establishing analogies there's really no parallel to a dispatcher. It's more of an unfortunate fact that we have to obsess with them in coroutines, for two reasons: there are special threads (like the UI), and you can't preemptively suspend a misbehaving coroutine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235948/discussion-between-emanuel-moecklin-and-marko-topolnik).

Comment: It's inevitable that threads leak into the coroutine logic (as you mention). I noticed that `Dispatchers.IO` should probably be replaced by `ioExecutor.asCoroutineDispatcher()` if we want to obsess with details ;-).